# Windows Vista ICS staying local only

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, windows-vista, network-shares

I hope i can get some help. So here is my scenario then my question.

**Scenario:**

I have a laptop running Windows Vista Home Premium (Wireless and Ethernet adapter), A desktop running Windows XP (Ethernet Adapter ONLY) and a Router. I am using my roomates Internet (Laptop connected to his router via wifi).

**Current hookup:**

[Here is a schematic of my hookup.](https://picasaweb.google.com/115497046360598879839/Schematic?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCPjxw72TteaQ7wE&feat=directlink)

Roommates Router is set to DHCP and its 192.168.0.1

My Router is also set to DHCP and its 192.168.2.1

All NIC and wifi cards are set to automatic DHCP

Windows Vista Laptop connected to Roommates Router via wifi. Internet works (ICS ENABLED HERE)

Windows Vista Laptop connected to my own router via Ethernet to a Lan Port 1 on my Router.

Windows XP machine connected to my own router via Ethernet to Lan Port 2 on my Router

**Issue:**

The moment I connect an Ethernet cable to my Vista Laptop from my own router, my wifi connection from the laptop to roommates wifi router goes local. I still have a valid IP address but no access to the web and status shows local only. In the Networking page, the network schematic shows my windows vista laptop connected to 'multiple networks' and then no connection to the internet.

**What I want to do:**

I would like to use my Windows Vista Laptop to share the connection with my windows XP desktop. I do not want to run any cables throughout the 4200 sqft home. My intent is to have my Vista Laptop continue to connect to his wifi router and share that connection with my desktop.

Is this possible?